# Beginner Question - Prompts , variables and scopes

Tags: javascript, function, scope, prompt

I am trying to make a global scoped variable which stores a prompt value (player's name) but only fire when I click on the Start button.(This is why the variable is not declared outside the function Start)

How can I make this variable value (the name of the player) accessible to other functions, but only call the prompt when I click the start button?

```
 Game.start.onclick = function Start(){  
  let namePlayer1 = prompt("Hello Player 1 ! What is your name?");
  let namePlayer2 = prompt("Hello Player 2 ! What is your name?"); 

 return alert(namePlayer1 + "- You have the symbol 'X'.\n"+ namePlayer2 +
      "- You have the symbol 'O'.\nClick on the button Change Turn to start!")
 }
```

Comment: You declared these variables inside a function, so their scope is inside this function. If you want them accessible outside, then declare them outside (and change their value inside the function, this is still good).

Comment: Yes , I know . But if I declare them outside , the prompt is called before I click the start button !!

Comment: you want to declare the variables in your global scope, but not assign them any value, just like `let namePlayer1;`
Then simply remove the let keyword inside of your function and you should be all set!

Comment: in your first line of javascript code just write var namePlayer1 ="", namePlayer2 ="" and remove the let partonly in the start.onlick function

Comment: Yes , know I understand what you were saying @ArthurBoucher.  In fact , I wanted to change the global variable throught a function

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Jeremy and @Arthur mentioned in the comments could look like this. You should move only declaration of variables outside, not whole initialisation with `prompt` function call.

```
let namePlayer1;
let namePlayer2;

Game.start.onclick = function Start() {
    namePlayer1 = prompt("Hello Player 1 ! What is your name?");
    namePlayer2 = prompt("Hello Player 2 ! What is your name?");

    return alert(
      namePlayer1 +
        "- You have the symbol 'X'.\n" +
        namePlayer2 +
        "- You have the symbol 'O'.\nClick on the button Change Turn to start!"
    );
};
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: Thank you !! I managed to do it !!

I was using the "let" keyword inside the function which was preventing me from changing the global variable to the name returned in the prompt.